# How to set advanced settings while uploading videos to Youtube using google-youtube api php

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have created the php script below that uploads videos to youtube and it uploads fine.

I would like to be able to set advanced settings to the uploaded video as follows:

- Allow comments should be "approved" not "All"
- I also need to be able to set the video location(this would come from
  the database from my site)
- I should also need to be able to set the recording date(to the date
  of the upload)
- I also don't want the video statistics to be publicly visible

I have looked around, but i cannot find any documentation on this from google, and i think google have not provided complete documentation for the API.

Any links will also do. Thanks

```
require_once '../google_api/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google_api/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '514750847005.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '9mvQL0NPv1zEOty0tZw71O4t';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri("{$redirect}");

$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
                die('The session state did not match.');
            }

            $client->authenticate();
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }
        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            try {
                $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
                $snippet->setTitle($title);
                $snippet->setDescription($desc);
                $snippet->setTags($tags);
                $snippet->setCategoryId(22);

                $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
                $status->privacyStatus = "public";

                $today = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
                $recordingDetails = new Google_VideoRecordingDetails();
                $recordingDetails->setRecordingDate($today);

                $video = new Google_Video();
                $video->setSnippet($snippet);
                $video->setStatus($status);
                $video->setRecordingDetails($recordingDetails);

                // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
                // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
                $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                // Create a MediaFileUpload with resumable uploads
                $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $media->setFileSize(filesize($vd_file));

                // Create a video insert request
                $insertResponse = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video, array('mediaUpload' => $media));

                $uploadStatus = false;

                // Read file and upload chunk by chunk
                $handle = fopen($vd_file, "rb");
                while (!$uploadStatus && !feof($handle)) {
                    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                    $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($insertResponse, $chunk);
                }

                fclose($handle);
                msg_add('suces', 'message', 'Youtube video upload was successful');
            } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
                $message = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
                msg_add('err', 'message', $message);
            } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                $message = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
                msg_add('err', 'message', $message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is simply a video->insert call. You are editing snippet, status and recordingDetails. You can do more by adding the other fields to the [VIDEOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) resource.

Fill in any field of the [VIDEOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) resource before inserting, that should do.

Comment: Thanks @ibrahim-ulukaya for your answer. But when i go through that list i can not find options to change most of the settings. For example, I cannot change the visibility of the video statistics and i can not change comments to "approved" from the default "all". If you also look at the code, you'll notice that I added a Google_VideoRecordingDetails object. This was an attempt to set the recording date and location(using longitude and latitude), but they don't show up after upload. My perception is that youtube only sends these fields in a video resource, but does not read them when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar situation where I was trying to set the location on insert but it was not working.  I got my code to correctly set location by including "recordingDetails" in the `part` parameter which is a comma separated list ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)).  I am using C#, so for me it looks like this:

```
var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status,recordingDetails", fileStream, "video/*");
```

From your sample it looks like in php this would be

```
$insertResponse = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet,recordingDetails", $video, array('mediaUpload' => $media));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Allow comments should be "approved" not "All"

It seems that's a youtube bug:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7664